# Web App Development - Graphing App Required - Advice?

Tags: php, web-applications

I am about to make an application which takes data and serves various types of graph up that plot this data. I am currently researching the frameworks etc that will need to be used for such a project. The application will be run online and currently I am thinking of using Flash/HTML for the front end and PHP for interrogating the database. I looked into what seemed like a decent package (JP Graph) but am open to suggestions of any other packages that can be used? Anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can really recommend [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). I've tested a lot of different graphlibs and this is by far the best one I've tried. Looks great, easy to use and is a lot better to tweak to your needs than others like for instance Google charts (which also is a decent lib).

Answer (score 1):

Google RaphaelJS, your jaw will drop.  ;-)

http://g.raphaeljs.com/ has some specific examples

Answer (score 1):

i'm using for that purposes nice framework http://dhtmlx.com/
it has modern charts, grids, layouts, toolbars and so on.
full documentation and tech support.